# Dropping files onto ag-grid to upload to a folder

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to extend the File browser example from the **ag-Grid** documentation site (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-file-browser) with a 'drop-files-to-upload' function.

[image]

The idea is that a user can drop files anywhere onto the grid. The app should then detect where the file was dropped (folder/ file path or an empty area). With the upload, the app can then send that information to the server.

I added **ng2-file-upload** (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) to handle the file drop event and the upload itself.

Demo from what I have so far here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvspzq

The problem I have is that I haven't found a good way to detect files being dropped onto the grid AND being able to get the context. In the demo I've used a combination of the (ng2-file-upload) `onFileDrop` event (to detect the files being dropped) and ag-grid's `cellMouseOver` event (to get the context). This works reasonably well, but does require that the user moves the mouse cursor after the drop: if they don't do that, the `cellMouseOver` event isn't triggered.

Any suggestions?